# The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "custom" component Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, uicomponent

I am facing this error due to custom field-set on the category form. Those attributes are related to the **Affirm Payment**.
Error i am getting,

> "1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "componentType"
> configuration parameter is required for the "custom" component.
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The
> "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "custom"
> component."

Please check below screenshot, Those are affirm attributes.
[image]

Attributes works fine, i am getting error only when i click on the Schedule New Update button from category edit page. Please check below screenshot for the code and error.
This is the button where i click for the schedule,
[image]

category_form.xml file code for the Affirm Payment method.
[image]

The error i am getting while click on the schedule button.
[image]

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Have you found a solution for it?

Comment: @cjochum i just posted the code. Please check and let me know if it won't work. Please upvote if it works fine for you. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching for long time, I found the solution by overriding the module.
Please check the below code,

create module.xml file on app\code\Vendorname\Affirm\etc

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendorname_Affirm" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Astound_Affirm"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

create catalogstaging_category_update_form.xml on this path, app\code\Vendorname\Affirm\view\adminhtml\ui_component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="affirm_category_mfp">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Multiple Financing Program value</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="affirm_category_mfp_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Astound\Affirm\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\FinancingProgramType</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Multiple Financing Program type</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="affirm_category_mfp_priority">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Multiple Financing Program priority</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="affirm_category_mfp_start_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">datetime</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start date for time based Financing Program value</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="affirm_category_mfp_end_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">datetime</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">End date for time based Financing Program value</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="affirm_category_promo_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Affirm Promo ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please create a custom module and put this code in respective files. Please let me know if this code does not works.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you! That was super helpful.